# TSQL: existential grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to get all the `Room_IDs` in `TABLE_A` where the `Status` has always been 'Vacant' and does not exist in `TABLE_B`.

This is a simplified table I am using as an example:

```
TABLE_A
**Room_Id   Status    Inspection_Date**
    1        vacant      5/15/2015
    2        occupied    5/21/2015
    2        vacant      1/19/2016
    1        occupied   12/16/2015
    4        vacant      3/25/2016
    3        vacant      8/27/2015
    1        vacant      4/17/2016
    3        vacant     12/12/2015
    3        vacant      3/22/2016
    4        vacant       2/2/2015
    4        vacant      3/24/2015

TABLE_B
**Room_Id   Status    Inspection_Date**
    1        vacant      5/15/2015
    2        occupied    5/21/2015
    2        vacant      1/19/2016
    1        vacant      12/16/2015
    4        vacant      3/25/2016
    1        vacant      4/17/2016
    4        vacant       2/2/2015
    4        vacant      3/24/2015
```

My result should look like this:

```
 **Room_Id  Status  Inspection_Date**
    3       vacant      8/27/2015
    3       vacant     12/12/2015
    3       vacant      3/22/2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  The subquery calculates the number of days which each room has been occupied in `TABLE_A`.  This result is then joined to `TABLE_B`, and only those rooms which did *not* match and *also* had a zero occupancy rate are returned in the result set.

```
SELECT t1.Room_Id, t3.Status, t3.Inspection_Date
FROM
(
    SELECT Room_Id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status != 'vacant' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nonVacancyCount
    FROM TABLE_A
    GROUP BY Room_Id
) t1
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_B t2
    ON t1.Room_Id = t2.Room_Id
INNER JOIN
TABLE_A t3
    ON t1.Room_Id = t3.Room_Id
WHERE t2.Room_Id IS NULL AND t1.nonVacancyCount = 0
```

One advantage of this approach is relative speed, since it does not use a correlated subquery.

**Follow the link below for a working demo:**

## SQLFiddle

(Note: The fiddle is in MySQL because SQL Server did not appear to be working.

Answer (score 1):

And in addition to the other answers, here's another way using a correlated exists predicate:

```
select * 
from table_a a
where not exists (
       select 1 
       from table_a 
       where room_id = a.room_id 
       and status <> 'vacant'
    )
and room_id not in (select room_id from table_b)
```

It's almost a literal translation from your query statement.

Answer (score 0):

First get all the room_id's in table_a where the status is always vacant using conditional aggregation.

Then, use `except` to get only those room_id's which don't exist in table_b.

Finally, select all the rows from table_a for such room_id's.

```
select * from table_a
where room_id in (
select room_id
from table_a 
group by room_id
having sum(case when status <> 'vacant' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
except
select room_id
from table_b
)
```